# Derivation of equation of hyperbola - Where does the b²=c²-a² come from?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, analytic-geometry, triangles, conic-sections

I'm learning about conic sections as defined using focci.

Every derivation I find for the hyperbola get's this definition out of the blue:
$b²=c²-a²$

It totally looks like a triangle somewhere, but when I see $a$ and $c$ they are parallel and I cant find how to form a triangle from them.

for example [in this definition](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/conics/hypdef.html) it's just stated

> Let's define $b^2 = c^2 - a^2$ and make the substitution into the equation.

With no explaination.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Equation) also justs states

> Remove the square roots by suitable squarings and use the relation
> $b^{2}=c^{2}-a^{2}$ to
> obtain the equation of the hyperbola:

For reference, I'm defining $a,b,c$ as in the following image,
where

- $b$ is a distance along the $y$ axis
- $a$ and $c$ are distances along the $x$ axis (to the vertex and focus
  respectively)

[image]

**The question:** why is the pythagorean theorem applied here, is there a sneaky triangle that can be defined? how/why does $c$ suddenly become a hipotenuse?